# swift возобновляемые подписки

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть приложение, где уже присутствует auto-renewable subscription, уже выложен в appstore, сейчас я переделал приложение и прошлая подписка ушла за не надобностью (создал другие auto-renewable subscription).

Такой вопрос : стоит ли удалять старую auto-renewable subscription и можно  ли сделать скидку на одну из новых auto-renewable subscription тем, кто купил старую auto-renewable subscription ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. удалять не стоит, т.к. у тех, кто не обновился - перестанут проходить покупки
2. вы можете написать логику, в которой будете отслеживать когда unit подписки закончится, тогда можно будет предложить новую (опять же она будет с той ценной, которую вы указали в app store connect, если хотите цену ниже - делайте отдельный productId)